# MySQL 8.0.3 can't start: Failed to open log

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Very similar problem to this:
[MAMP Mysql Error - Failed to open log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443025/mamp-mysql-error-failed-to-open-log)

When I start mysqld I get this error:

```
2017-11-12T16:45:18.532594Z 0 [Note] Basedir set to D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\
2017-11-12T16:45:18.535678Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-11-12T16:45:18.535725Z 0 [Note] D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.3-rc-log) starting as process 1888 ...
2017-11-12T16:45:18.544007Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-11-12T16:45:18.547052Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-12T16:45:18.547385Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-11-12T16:45:18.547571Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-11-12T16:45:18.547864Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2017-11-12T16:45:18.548397Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-11-12T16:45:18.548682Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-11-12T16:45:18.551490Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-11-12T16:45:18.560084Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-12T16:45:18.574457Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.2' max LSN: 17207612
2017-11-12T16:45:18.581017Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...
2017-11-12T16:45:18.581293Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!
2017-11-12T16:45:18.588909Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.
2017-11-12T16:45:18.713439Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-11-12T16:45:18.713969Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-11-12T16:45:18.791833Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-11-12T16:45:18.803915Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.
2017-11-12T16:45:18.805048Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 17235597
2017-11-12T16:45:18.908135Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-12T16:45:18.909158Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171112 17:45:18
2017-11-12T16:45:18.924130Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1
mysqld: File '2017-11-12T16:13:21.085592Z 0 [Note] Binlog end' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-12T16:45:18.949600Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-12T16:13:21.085592Z 0 [Note] Binlog end', errno 13)
2017-11-12T16:45:18.949966Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
2017-11-12T16:45:18.950149Z 0 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2017-11-12T16:45:18.950333Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2017-11-12T16:45:18.950532Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-11-12T16:45:18.951277Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-11-12T16:45:18.951697Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.951900Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.952105Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.952302Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'TempTable'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.952503Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.952761Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.952969Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.953167Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CACHED_INDEXES'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.953403Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_VIRTUAL'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.953616Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_COLUMNS'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.953830Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TABLESPACES'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.954054Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_INDEXES'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.954269Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TABLESTATS'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.954491Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TABLES'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.954703Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.954936Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.955184Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.955415Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.955653Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.955876Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.956124Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.956366Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.956603Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.956844Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.957083Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.957308Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.957556Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.957788Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.958017Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.958253Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.958472Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.958674Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.958876Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2017-11-12T16:45:18.959079Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-11-12T16:45:19.060124Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-12T16:45:19.065546Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 171112 17:45:19
2017-11-12T16:45:20.317846Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 17262731
2017-11-12T16:45:20.318363Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-11-12T16:45:20.318697Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-11-12T16:45:20.318901Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-11-12T16:45:20.319092Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha2_cache_cleaner'
2017-11-12T16:45:20.319353Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'caching_sha2_password'
2017-11-12T16:45:20.319628Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-11-12T16:45:20.319871Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-11-12T16:45:20.320323Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-11-12T16:45:20.320805Z 0 [Note] D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

I can't find any 'var' folder in my mysql folder, nor 'mysql-bin.index' file anywhere in my computer. I don't know where mysqld is expecting that file to be.

How can I fix this and start my mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, the file is called DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.index in my computer and was found under the data folder where mysql stores the database.

I emptied the content of this index file and mysql is running again. I don't understand why or whether it actually was the reason. This was what I found in that file, which looks a lot like a log file so I wasn't expecting to see an effect:

```
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000001
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000002
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000003
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000004
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000005
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000006
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000007
2017-11-06T17:59:54.541193Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-11-06T17:59:54.568351Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-06T17:59:54.569146Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-11-06T17:59:54.569631Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-11-06T17:59:54.570530Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2017-11-06T17:59:54.575411Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-11-06T17:59:54.578906Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-11-06T17:59:54.583104Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-11-06T17:59:54.596966Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-06T17:59:54.632081Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 15225091 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 16647247 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-11-06T17:59:54.632584Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-11-06T17:59:54.632812Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-11-06T17:59:54.641979Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.1' max LSN: 16286950
2017-11-06T17:59:54.646957Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16647247
2017-11-06T17:59:54.655170Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...
2017-11-06T17:59:54.655443Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!
2017-11-06T17:59:54.655934Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 49567, file name DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000007
2017-11-06T17:59:54.774590Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.
2017-11-06T17:59:54.889740Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-11-06T17:59:54.890052Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-11-06T17:59:54.890506Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-11-06T17:59:54.918638Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-11-06T17:59:54.930557Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.
2017-11-06T17:59:54.931664Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 16647247
2017-11-06T17:59:55.104098Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-06T17:59:55.112864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171106 18:59:55
2017-11-06T17:59:55.125772Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1
2017-11-06T17:59:55.158741Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin
2017-11-06T17:59:55.161192Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2017-11-06T17:59:55.161700Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2017-11-06T17:59:55.167187Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : begin
2017-11-06T17:59:55.167744Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : end
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000008
2017-11-11T09:26:35.045541Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.056583Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-11T09:26:35.056920Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-11-11T09:26:35.057170Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-11-11T09:26:35.057635Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2017-11-11T09:26:35.058767Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-11-11T09:26:35.059330Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-11-11T09:26:35.062500Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-11-11T09:26:35.072049Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-11T09:26:35.102431Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 15225091 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 16692836 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-11-11T09:26:35.102971Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-11-11T09:26:35.103263Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.112811Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.1' max LSN: 16674515
2017-11-11T09:26:35.117119Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16692836
2017-11-11T09:26:35.120889Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...
2017-11-11T09:26:35.121187Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!
2017-11-11T09:26:35.121696Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 5073, file name DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000008
2017-11-11T09:26:35.240881Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.371010Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-11-11T09:26:35.371324Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-11-11T09:26:35.371763Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-11-11T09:26:35.400748Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.417187Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.418663Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 16692836
2017-11-11T09:26:35.562126Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-11T09:26:35.567929Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171111 10:26:35
2017-11-11T09:26:35.578991Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1
2017-11-11T09:26:35.614146Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin
2017-11-11T09:26:35.614545Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2017-11-11T09:26:35.614842Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.621462Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : begin
2017-11-11T09:26:35.622032Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : end
.\DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000009
2017-11-11T09:26:35.649708Z 0 [Warning] You have not provided a mandatory server-id. Servers in a replication topology must have unique server-ids. Please refer to the proper server start-up parameters documentation.
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.622032Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : end' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.652612Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.622032Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : end', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.653021Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.621462Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : begin' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.653227Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.621462Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: DDL log recovery : begin', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.653707Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.614842Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.653925Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.614842Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.654308Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.614545Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.654515Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.614545Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.654902Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.614146Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.655106Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.614146Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.655603Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.578991Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.655856Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.578991Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.656293Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.567929Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171111 10:26:35' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.656541Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.567929Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171111 10:26:35', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.657052Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.562126Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.657323Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.562126Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool', errno 2)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.657917Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.418663Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 16692836' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.658126Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.418663Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 16692836', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.658615Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.417187Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.658836Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.417187Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.659467Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.400748Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.659704Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.400748Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.', errno 2)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.660132Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.371763Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.660357Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.371763Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...', errno 2)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.660959Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.371324Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.661167Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.371324Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.661661Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.371010Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.661865Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.371010Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.662333Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.240881Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.662556Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.240881Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.663015Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.121696Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 5073, file name DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000008' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.663262Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.121696Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 5073, file name DESKTOP-FBF6RQE-bin.000008', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.663834Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.121187Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.664039Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.121187Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.664438Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.120889Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.664646Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.120889Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.665143Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.117119Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16692836' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.665347Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.117119Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16692836', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.665872Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.112811Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.1' max LSN: 16674515' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.666101Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.112811Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.1' max LSN: 16674515', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.666562Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.103263Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.666766Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.103263Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.667191Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.102971Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.667397Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.102971Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.667832Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.102431Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 15225091 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 16692836 in the ib_logfiles!' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.668041Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.102431Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 15225091 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 16692836 in the ib_logfiles!', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.668749Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.072049Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.668957Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.072049Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.669403Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.062500Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.669612Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.062500Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.670158Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.059330Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.670360Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.059330Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.670794Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.058767Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.670998Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.058767Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.671387Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.057635Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.671619Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.057635Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.672046Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.057170Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.672251Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.057170Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.672786Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.056920Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.673023Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.056920Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.673502Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.056583Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.673716Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.056583Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.674201Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.045541Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.674407Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.045541Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.', errno 13)
2017-11-11T09:26:35.674845Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
2017-11-11T09:26:35.681224Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-11-11T09:26:35.681793Z 0 [Note] RSA private key file not found: D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\\private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.682297Z 0 [Note] RSA public key file not found: D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\\public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.688653Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-11-11T09:26:35.689168Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.689387Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-11-11T09:26:35.689632Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-11-11T09:26:35.730516Z 4 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 4
2017-11-11T09:26:35.730787Z 0 [Note] D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.3-rc-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-11-12T16:09:13.321752Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-11-12T16:09:13.327276Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-12T16:09:13.327587Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-11-12T16:09:13.327769Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-11-12T16:09:13.328054Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2017-11-12T16:09:13.328580Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-11-12T16:09:13.328865Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-11-12T16:09:13.331962Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-11-12T16:09:13.342562Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-12T16:09:13.357255Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.1' max LSN: 16739055
2017-11-12T16:09:13.361358Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...
2017-11-12T16:09:13.361631Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!
2017-11-12T16:09:13.369632Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.
2017-11-12T16:09:13.497034Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-11-12T16:09:13.497544Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-11-12T16:09:13.524418Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-11-12T16:09:13.535690Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.
2017-11-12T16:09:13.536818Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 16766170
2017-11-12T16:09:13.631459Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-12T16:09:13.632940Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171112 17:09:13
2017-11-12T16:09:13.650952Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1
mysqld: File '2017-11-11T09:26:35.730787Z 0 [Note] D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.3-rc-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-12T16:09:13.677325Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-11T09:26:35.730787Z 0 [Note] D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.3-rc-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)', errno 13)
2017-11-12T16:09:13.678104Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
2017-11-12T16:09:13.678282Z 0 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2017-11-12T16:09:13.678442Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2017-11-12T16:09:13.678643Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-11-12T16:09:13.679389Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-11-12T16:10:30.147427Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-11-12T16:10:30.153362Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-12T16:10:30.153890Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-11-12T16:10:30.154257Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-11-12T16:10:30.154768Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2017-11-12T16:10:30.155720Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-11-12T16:10:30.156585Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-11-12T16:10:30.162241Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-11-12T16:10:30.173293Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-12T16:10:30.198754Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.2' max LSN: 16766189
2017-11-12T16:10:30.203195Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...
2017-11-12T16:10:30.203485Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!
2017-11-12T16:10:30.211017Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.
2017-11-12T16:10:30.346852Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-11-12T16:10:30.347381Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-11-12T16:10:30.376752Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-11-12T16:10:30.388120Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.
2017-11-12T16:10:30.389122Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 16794174
2017-11-12T16:10:30.494659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-12T16:10:30.495981Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171112 17:10:30
2017-11-12T16:10:30.511094Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1
mysqld: File '2017-11-12T16:09:13.679389Z 0 [Note] Binlog end' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-12T16:10:30.536218Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-12T16:09:13.679389Z 0 [Note] Binlog end', errno 13)
2017-11-12T16:10:30.536677Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
2017-11-12T16:10:30.536873Z 0 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2017-11-12T16:10:30.537050Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2017-11-12T16:10:30.537232Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-11-12T16:10:30.538030Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-11-12T16:13:20.723327Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-11-12T16:13:20.726715Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-11-12T16:13:20.727050Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-11-12T16:13:20.727255Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-11-12T16:13:20.727566Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2017-11-12T16:13:20.728253Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-11-12T16:13:20.728858Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-11-12T16:13:20.733263Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-11-12T16:13:20.744173Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-11-12T16:13:20.759094Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using 'tablespaces.open.2' max LSN: 16821327
2017-11-12T16:13:20.763132Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Applying a batch of 0 redo log records ...
2017-11-12T16:13:20.763398Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed!
2017-11-12T16:13:20.771518Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 2 existing undo tablespaces.
2017-11-12T16:13:20.898543Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-11-12T16:13:20.899066Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-11-12T16:13:20.927231Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-11-12T16:13:20.938469Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Created 128 and tracked 128 new rollback segment(s) in the temporary tablespace. 128 are now active.
2017-11-12T16:13:20.939685Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: 8.0.3 started; log sequence number 16849296
2017-11-12T16:13:21.038115Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\ProgramFiles\mysql-8.0.3-rc-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-11-12T16:13:21.039792Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171112 17:13:21
2017-11-12T16:13:21.058281Z 1 [Note] Found data dictionary with version 1
mysqld: File '2017-11-12T16:10:30.538030Z 0 [Note] Binlog end' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-11-12T16:13:21.083974Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '2017-11-12T16:10:30.538030Z 0 [Note] Binlog end', errno 13)
2017-11-12T16:13:21.084329Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open log file
2017-11-12T16:13:21.084507Z 0 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2017-11-12T16:13:21.084669Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2017-11-12T16:13:21.084858Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-11-12T16:13:21.085592Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
```

Comment: Reviewing this information,
A. you are running rc - release candidate version of software.  Not typically done for production systems.
B. replication candidate is involved and REQUIRES server id
C. you now have permissions squared away that were an earlier problem.
D. starting at the top, documentation exists for each problem found.